# C# SQLite Как удалить файл базы данных?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Намеренно удаляю базу данных, делаю запрос и обрабатываю ошибки, и остается от БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как удалять этот файл?

```
protected bool Delete() {
  using(var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Globals.connection)) {
    try {
      connection.Open();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException) {
      connection.Close();
      return false;
    }
    using(var command = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM system_events", connection)) {
      try { 
        if(command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0) {
          connection.Close();
          try {
            File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\db\\db.db");
          } catch (Exception) {
          }
          return false;
        }
      } catch(SQLiteException) {
        connection.Close();
        try {
            File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\db\\db.db");
        } catch (Exception) {
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
    connection.Close();
  }
  return true;  
}
```

Comment: вы же не первый раз вопрос задаете. Какой код? Какие ошибки обрабатываете и как? Почему вы ожидаете, что файл удалится? Или от чего вам надо избавляться?

Comment: Ну если вы хотите удалить БД совсем, то не проще ли просто взять и удалить сам файл `File.Delete("путь к файлу /db")` ? Если вы используете `using(var connection ….)`,  то `connection.Dispose();` не нужно писать, с `connection.Dispose();` такая же петрушка.

Comment: Команда [DELETE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html) удаляет _данные_, но не саму базу данных. Обычно используется `DROP DATABASE`, но в sqlite такой команды нет, потому что это встраиваемый движок. Поэтому используйте `File.Delete`, как уже сказали выше.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov File.Delete не работает, UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы (не описывайте проблемы) в комментариях. Создайте новую тему. Это исключение никак не связано с первоначальным вопросом.

Comment: Вы назначили награду за решение чего? Прочитайте сами свою тему: в ней нет вопроса. На что отвечать? А главное, вам все же дали в комментариях и пояснение (delete удаляет данные, но не саму БД), и ответ: sqlite не имеет команды удаления БД, поэтому используйте удаление файла.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov удаление файла не работает, я же написал

Comment: Я в упор не вижу команды удаления файла в вашем коде.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ok, обновил

Comment: Блин, если ваша цель - полностью удалить БД, то выкиньте _весь_ код удаления _данных_, оставьте _одну_ строку: `File.Delete(...);`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет, моя цель показать сообщение что не связи с базой данных если файл базы данных будет удален и в программе пользователь попытается сделать запрос к ней. "DELETE FROM system_events" - не попытка удалить базу данных а чистка таблицы. Я знаю что можно проверять наличие файла базы данных перед каждым действием, но мне просто интересно почему SQLite оставляет 0 bytes файл

Comment: А что по вашему должно остаться? Если данные удалены полностью - остается пустой файл. Его размер 0 байт. Сам файл sqlite не удаляет.

Comment: Елки зеленые, автор... У Вас не "не работает удаление файла", у Вас, а вернее, у пользователя от имени которого запускается Ваше приложение, не хватает прав чтобы его удалить. Судя по коду Вы ищете файл в рабочей папке приложения, из какой папки оно запускается? Если из какой-либо системной папки, то это абсолютно верно и логично, что пользователю не дают туда писать, когда приложение не запущено от имени админа (или из под sudo в случае *nix). Если приложению надо что-то создавать и удалять, то это самое что-то следует класть в личную папку пользователя, скорее всего тогда это дадут удалить.

Answer (score 7):

Команда `DELETE` удаляет данные, но не саму базу данных.

Окроме того это **нормально** что остается пустой файл размером в 0 байт. Это то же самое, что создать пустой текстовый документ, сохранить там 0 символов и жаловаться что операционка не удалила сам файл, хотя он, вроде как, пустой и должен удалиться...

**Сам файл БД при удалении данных из БД удалятся НЕ ДОЛЖЕН даже в теории.**

Раз уж ты имеешь желание удалить сам файл базы данных, то нужно использовать `File.Delete(@"\db\db.db");` -- то есть банальное удаление файла через файловую систему операционки.

`UnauthorizedAccessException` может возникать в случаях:

- если база данных сейчас используется. То есть нужно сначала закрыть Connection к базе данных (полностью отключится от нее), а потом удалить сам файл.
- Если база данных размещается там, куда пользователь (от имени которого запущена прога) не имеет доступа. Решение: или разместить прогу туда, куда есть доступ у простого пользователя, или же запускай саму апликуху(и вижуалку) от имени администратора.

Пример кода:

```
protected bool Delete() {
    //Пытаемся отключить конекшн к БД если он открыт.
    try {
        _connection.Close(); //_connection -- глобальная переменная класса. Эта переменная должна использоваться и в других местах! И открываться конекшн должен только из одного места. НЕ НУЖНО ПЛОДИТЬ ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЯ К БД
    catch(SQLiteException) {
        //Ошибка здесь не важна. Если он закрыт, значит уже прекрасно!
    }

    try {
        //Наш коннекшн закрыт. Можем смело удалять сам файл.
        File.Delete(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\db\\db.db");

        return true;//Ура! Нам удалось удалить файл!
    } catch (Exception) {
    }

    //Во всех иных случаях мы потерпели неудачу
    return false;  
}
```

Не забываем что желательно прога должна запускаться от имени админа компа, если какие-то хитрые настройки доступа в операционной системе!